# How to make a bookmarklet "installable"

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that I want to install on an iOS device. The problem is that it's tricky and user-hostile.

I've seen some apps work around this by using a special webpage. When the webpage is bookmarked, it actually results in the bookmarklet's code being added. The URL of the bookmark doesn't need to be edited manually when they're installed in this manner.

I've been looking for how to do this but I'm not sure what mechanism it uses or where to begin looking.

Answer (score 0):

Still looking for a better solution, but this is what I found so far. The best solution might be to have the bookmarklet encoded into the URL, like this:

```
http://example.com/index.html?bm=javascript:code...
```

When the user adds the bookmarklet, they only have to edit it and remove everything before the "javascript" in order to make it work. You could also use JavaScript to place the bookmarklet code into the URL when loading the page.

I was *almost* certain that I had some apps where I was able to use the iOS share sheet to add a bookmarklet without modifications, but I think that those were home screen web apps, not bookmarklets. (In home screen apps, you can use the `window.navigator.standalone` variable to determine if it's a home screen app and do the appropriate actions).